# How do you play sound through a specified audio device on Android?

Tags: android, android-tv

I need to be able to play a sound through a specific audio device, rather than the default audio device.

The app lives on an Android media box, and the default audio device is the HDMI output. However, I need to be able to play a sound through a different connected audio device (such as a USB or Bluetooth speaker).